# create a static method to access the properties of a list of instance

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, static-methods

I create entity classes for the tables of my database. I use Dapper to create lists of the objects when I read multiple records from the database. In my classes I have two non-static methods, InsertStatement and UpdateStatement. They both return the SQL string necessary for Dapper Execute to insert or update the current instance back into the database. I'd like to add a new static method that would return a single SQL Insert statement for all the instances of my objects in my list. Putting it another way, I'd like to create a static method, in the entity class, that can iterate through all the instances of the object in a list and access all the properties for each instance.

Any thoughts?

Ultimately, the returned SQL statement would look something like,

```
INSERT INTO myTable (property1, property2)
    VALUES ("text1", 5), ("moreText", 27), ("etc.",50), ("etc.",65), ("etc.",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq

public class Banana
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public static string GetSql(List<Banana> bananas)
    {
        string _operator = "INSERT INTO bananaTable (id, name) VALUES ";
        string _val = null;

        foreach (var item in bananas)
        {
            _val += $" ({item.id}, '{item.name})'";

            if (item != bananas.Last())
                _val += ", ";
        }

        return _operator + _val + "; ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to injection.

Comment: duh... I don't know why I didn't think to pass the list in as a parameter. Thanks.